# Increment value in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting data from a payload which has a total number of likes on each post. On the user screen, there's an icon for the user to like a post and what i want to achieve is when the user taps on it, the value show be increased to plus 1 against that particular post

VIEW:

```
{
  posts.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <View key={i} style={styles.user}>
        <Card>

          <ListItem
            titleStyle={{ color: '#36c', fontWeight:'500' }}
            titleNumberOfLines={2}
            hideChevron={false}
            roundAvatar
            title={item.headline}
            avatar={{uri:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg'}}
          />

          <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize:16, color:'#4a4a4a', fontFamily:'HelveticaNeue-Light'}}>
            {item.text}
          </Text>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.likeContainer}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>{item.likesCount}{"\n"}</Text>
            <Icon
              onPress={()=>onLikePost(item)}
              name='md-thumbs-up'
              type='ionicon'
              iconStyle={[(item.isLiked=== true) ? styles.likedColor : styles.unLikedColor]}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  })
}
```

CONTAINER:

```
state = {
  posts : [],
  id: '',
  user: ''
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  this.setState({
    id : navigation.getParam('id'), 
    user: navigation.getParam('user')
  }, ()=> this.getData())
}

getData = () => {
  const api = create({
    baseURL: 'https://url.com/api',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
  });
  api.get('/groups/'+`${this.state.groupID}`+'/posts').then((response) => {
    let data = response.data.data
    this.setState({ posts: data });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.posts))
  })
}

onLikePost = (item) => {
  item.likeCount = item.likeCount+1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing posts data in state variable so use `setState` to update it. Use `map` and check for each post, whenever id (unique property of each post) matches to id of the clicked item, increase its likesCount otherwise return the same data.

Write it like this:

```
onLikePost = (item) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    posts: prevState.posts.map(el => el.id === item.id? {...el, likesCount: el.likesCount+1} : el)
  }))
}
```

**Update**: Put the check before updating the count value and change the isLiked `bool` also.

```
onLikePost = (item) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    posts: prevState.posts.map(el => {
      if(el.id === item.id) {
        return {
          ...el,
          isLiked: !el.isLiked,
          likesCount: !el.isLiked? el.likesCount+1 : el.likesCount-1,
        }
      }
      return el;
    })
  }))
}
```

**Note**: I am assuming each post has a key `id` unique value, if it doesn't exist then use any other unique property of the each post.

Comment: Thanks it worked. one more thing when the isLiked is changed to false can it do subtraction?

Comment: isLiked is fixed or it will change also onClick of like button?

Comment: it will change onClick

Comment: check the updated answer, let me know if it not working.

Comment: when the isLiked value is zero and you click it changes to NaN

Comment: there was a typo in count value try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189443/discussion-between-developer-and-mayank-shukla).

Answer (score 1):

If array sequence is not an issue, you can use item index and use `setState` to update it.

```
<Icon
  onPress={()=>onLikePost(i)}
  ...
/>

...

onLikePost = (i) => {
  let posts = this.state.posts;
  posts[i].likesCount = !posts[i].isLiked ? posts[i].likesCount + 1 : posts[i].likesCount - 1;
  posts[i].isLiked = !posts[i].isLiked;
  this.setState({ posts: posts}) 
}
```